# Control dynamic asyncio.Semaphore

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

Not sure if I'm taking the right approach. I need to change dynamically the amount of requests I'm sending, for this I thought I could change dynamically the amount of semaphores I'm running. Let's say I want 10 parallel calls during the first minute, then increase it to 20 for 2 minutes, then decrease it to 15, and so on, like a load-test. Is it possible to control `dynamic_value` during run-time?

```
async def send_cus(cus_id):
  async with ClientSession(connector=TCPConnector(limit=0)) as session:
    num_parallel = asyncio.Semaphore(dynamic_value)

    async def send_cust_2(cust_id):
      async with num_parallel:
        # do something ...

    tasks = list(send_cust_2(cust_id) for cus_id in my_ordered_lst)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: I think a semaphore is not the right abstraction for this kind of load-test. Instead, create a queue and feed it your ordered list. Use `asyncio.create_task` to create 10 workers to drain the queue. After a minute, create 10 more workers, then cancel 5, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't clarified this, but I'm running Python 3.6 (that's why I'm using await `asyncio.gather(*tasks)`), `asyncio.create_task` is Python 3.8.

Comment: In Python 3.6 and earlier you can use `loop.create_task(...)` instead, and obtain the loop with `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()`.